# Observable still subscribed after SelectMany

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive, reactiveui

I have the standard reactive-ui routing set up for a WPF app, and I have an interface that ViewModel's can implement to provide title information.

```
public interface IHaveTitle
{
    IObservable<string> Title { get; }
}
```

In one view model I'm doing the following (for demo purposes):

```
public IObservable<string> Title => Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Select(_ => DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
```

In my main window screen, I'm doing the following:

```
disposer(
    ViewModel.Router.CurrentViewModel
    .SelectMany(vm =>
        ((vm as IHaveTitle)?.Title.StartWith("") ?? 
            Observable.Return("")).Select(s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? vm.UrlPathSegment : $"{vm.UrlPathSegment} > {s}"))
    .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
    .BindTo(this, w => w.Title));
```

Where `disposer` is the `Action<IDisposable>` passed into the `this.WhenActivated` extension method.

Now, when I navigate around, the title does change to reflect the `UrlPathSegment`, and while on the primary view model the title updates to show the time every 5 seconds.

The problem I'm seeing however, is that even when I navigate to a different view model, the title observable on the primary view model is still leading to changes on the title.

My question really, is: How do I prevent this? Why isn't it detaching when I navigate away, given I'm selecting based on the `CurrentViewModel`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the use of `SelectMany`. You're saying "every time the `CurrentViewModel` changes, subscribe to this other observable". Since those observables never complete, they remain "active" forever.

You instead want to *switch* to the new observable:

```
disposer(
    ViewModel.Router.CurrentViewModel
    .Select(vm =>
        ((vm as IHaveTitle)?.Title.StartWith("") ?? 
            Observable.Return("")).Select(s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? vm.UrlPathSegment : $"{vm.UrlPathSegment} > {s}"))
    .Switch()
    .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
    .BindTo(this, w => w.Title));
```

Comment: I did wonder if `Switch` was what I was looking for, I'd just never used it before!